# Powershell Count File Extensions with Total File Size for Each Extension

Tags: file, powershell, size

I am taking a PowerShell course for beginners, and the instructor is completely useless when it comes to asking for help. The task I am trying to do is: search my computer for files ending with a .doc, .docx, .xls, or .xlsx file extension.
Output the filenames and sizes (in groups by file extension) to a text file named “File_Summary.txt”. The output should also conclude with a total of the number of files and total file size for each file extension. The code that I have created so far is:

```
$path = ".\"
$destination = "C:\Users\StayPositibve\Desktop\pleasework1.txt"

$results = Get-ChildItem .\* -Recurse | where {$_.extension -in ".doc",".docx",".xls",".xlsx"}  | Select-Object Name, Extension, @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1Kb) }}
$results | Sort-Object -Property extension | Out-File $destination
$countFiles = Get-ChildItem .\* -Recurse | where {$_.extension -in ".doc",".docx",".xls",".xlsx"} 
$countFiles | Group-Object -Property extension | Out-File $destination -Append
```

The code runs (although I'm sure it's terrible coding); however, I cannot figure out how to add the total file size for each extension together. I have the total number of files for each extension, but just not the size total. Thanks for any help anyone can give me!

Comment: I don't think you have a neat option without a loop; the cleanest I can think of would be to use `Group-Object -Property Extension` and store that in a variable, then use `$store | ForEach { $_.Name; $_.Group | Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length | Select -ExpandProperty Sum }` and see what that does, and work that into appending it to the file. (I also suggest you store the results of the basic Get-ChildItem call from the first time before doing anything, then you can reuse the results and not have to wait for it to search again for the file count).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use `Measure-Object` as TessellatingHeckler suggested. This will do what you are trying to accomplish:

```
$path = ".\"
$destination = "C:\Users\StayPositibve\Desktop\pleasework1.txt"

$results = Get-ChildItem .\* -Recurse | where {$_.extension -in ".doc",".docx",".xls",".xlsx"}  | Select-Object Name, Extension, @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1Kb) }}
$results | Sort-Object -Property extension | Out-File $destination
$results|group extension|select Count,Name,@{l='Total KB';e={$_.Group | Measure-Object -Property kbytes -Sum|select -expand sum}}| Out-File $destination -Append
```

I re-use `$results`, and group like you did, but then I use `Select` to add a new property where I get the total size of each grouping with `Measure-Object` piped to `Select -Expand Sum`.

Comment: Thanks TheMadTechnician and TessellatingHeckler for your help. Looking at your code, I can see where I had created two variables that did the same process instead of only using $results. I'm new at this so I am glad that I am slowly getting there lol. Thanks again!